# Don't generate Card in SharePoint Online List Gallery View (JSON)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have got a SharePoint list that i would like to display in a SharePoint Site.

Different Users should only see the elements that are meant for them. This is determined by the columns `Zielgruppen` (`targit group`) which is a `Multiple lines of text` field, and `Zielpersonen` (`targit persons`) which is a `Person` field.

If the User `@me` is not in `Zielpersonen` or the users Department (That's another question, how do I get the department of the User? Azure?) is not in `Zielgruppen` the Card should not be generated.

I've tried to change the display value to none but the card is still generated and takes up the space

```
"style": {
      "display": "=if ([$Zielgruppen] == '<<Users Department>>', 'flex', 'none')"
},
```

Comment: Any reason you are using "Multiple lines of text" column, are you adding multiple departments in single item OR department names are longer than 255 characters?

Comment: `Zielpersonen` is single selection or multiple selection people field?

Comment: Hi @Kirito, did you try my solution given below? let me know if you need any further help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get [department of people field using JSON formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#special-string-values) as well. Assuming internal name of your column is "Zielpersonen", you can get department like:

```
[$Zielpersonen.department]
```

So, try using this:

```
"style": {
    "display": "=if([$Zielgruppen] == [$Zielpersonen.department] || [$Zielpersonen.email] == @me, 'flex', 'none')"
},
```

You can get the correct internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Documentation**: [JSON formatting-syntax-reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference)